# C-like callback handling: which algorithm preforms faster?

Tags: c++, c, callback

I have an array of call backs like this `void (*callbacks[n])(void* sender)` and I'm wondering which one of these codes will preform faster :

```
//Method A
void nullcallback(void* sender){};

void callbacka(void* sender) 
{
    printf("Hello ");
}

void callbackb(void* sender)
{
    printf("world\n");
}

int main()
{
    void (*callbacks[5])(void* sender);
    unsigned i;
    for (i=0;i<5;++i)
        callbacks[i] = nullcallback;
    callbacks[2] = callbacka;
    callbacks[4] = callbackb;
    for (i=0;i<5;++i)
        callbacks[i](NULL);
};
```

or

```
//Method B
void callbacka(void* sender) 
{
    printf("Hello ");
}

void callbackb(void* sender)
{
    printf("world\n");
}

int main()
{
    void (*callbacks[5])(void* sender);
    unsigned i;
    for (i=0;i<5;++i)
        callbacks[i] = NULL;
    callbacks[2] = callbacka;
    callbacks[4] = callbackb;
    for (i=0;i<5;++i)
        if (callbacks[i])
            callbacks[i](NULL);
};
```

some conditions:

- Does it matter if I know most of my callbacks are valid or not?
- Does it make a difference if I'm compiling my code using C or C++ compiler?
- Does the target platform (windows, linux, mac, iOS, android) change any thing in the results? (the whole reason for this callback array is to manage callbacks in a game)

Comment: Wow, tiny micro-optimisations.  This is what profiling is for.  There is some interesting discussion on LKML on a similar topic though [null pointers](http://lwn.net/Articles/347390/).

Comment: Method B is faster. Because calling a function will consume more time than just a NULL comparison.

Comment: @steve there are too many conditions that I have to check so I thought maybe someone already checked those and could help me decide which one is better.

Comment: @stan: I was thinking same, but I'm not sure if that's true if most of callbacks are valid, let's talk about something 90% valid callbacks.

Comment: Your compiler, your architcture and your application. Time the two methods and remember that the results may not apply to a different compiler, different architecture or different application.

Comment: benchmark, benchmark, benchmark.

Comment: Please don't get into this unless you have profiler's output to confirm that it matters. In the meantime, do whatever produces more clean code.

Comment: a.k.a. [null object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern).

Comment: @Stan: Without timing it it is imposable to say but I doubt there will be any difference as a wrong branch on a test will cause the predictive branching to fail and force the processes to wind back the pipeline. Ultimately this kind of comparison is useless and the only thing you should worry about is readability (aka maintainability) and A is the most readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This totally depends on your actual situation. If possible I would prefer methode A, because it is simply easier to read and produce cleaner code, in particular if your function has a return value:

```
ret = callbacks[UPDATE_EVENT](sender);
// is nicer then
if (callbacks[UPDATE_EVENT])
    ret = callbacks[UPDATE_EVENT](sender);
else
    ret = 0;
```

Of course methode A becomes tedouis when you have not only one function signature but let's say 100 different signature. And for each you have to write a null function.

For the performance consideration it depends if the nullcallback() is a rare case or not. If it is rare, methode A is obviously faster. If not methode B could be slightly faster, but that depends on many factors: which platform you use, how many arguments your functions have, etc. But in any case if your callbacks are doing "real work", ie. not only some simple calculations, it shouldn't matter at all.

Where your methode B could really be faster is when you not only call the callback for one sender but for very many:

```
extern void *senders[SENDERS_COUNT]; // SENDERS_COUNT is a large number

if (callbacks[UPDATE_EVENT])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < SENDERS_COUNT; i++)
        callbacks[UPDATE_EVENT](senders[i]);
}
```

Here the entire loop is skipped when there is no valid callback. This tweak can also be done with methode A if the nullcallback() address is known, ie. not defined in some module only.

Answer (score 3):

You'd have to look into the assembler code for that. On my platform (gcc, 32bit) I found that the compiler is not able to optimize the call to `nullcallback` out. But if I improve your method A to the following

```
int main(void) {
  static void (*const callbacks[5])(void* sender) = {
    [0] = nullcallback,
    [1] = nullcallback,
    [2] = callbacka,
    [3] = nullcallback,
    [4] = callbackb,
  };
  for (unsigned i=0;i<5;++i)
        callbacks[i](0);
};
```

the compiler is able to unroll the loop and optimize the calls the result is just

```
    .type   main, @function
main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    andl    $-16, %esp
    subl    $16, %esp
    movl    $0, (%esp)
    call    callbacka
    movl    $0, (%esp)
    call    callbackb
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    leave
    ret
    .size   main, .-main
```

Answer (score 1):

You could optimize your code further by simply zero-initializing the array to start with like:

```
void (*callbacks[5])(void* sender) = { 0 };
```

Then you've completely eliminated the need for your for-loop to set each pointer to `NULL`.  You now just have to make assignments for `callbacka` and `callbackb`.

Comment: Alternatively if you use a vector and a the default constructor you can just as easily initialize all elements to nullcallback()

Comment: with C99 you could even just initialize with `{ [2] = callbacka, [4] = callbackb }`.

Answer (score 1):

For the general case *method B* is preferred, but for function pointer LUTs when NULL is the exception than *method A* is microscopically faster.

The primary example is Linux system call table, NULL calls should only occur in rare circumstances when running binaries built on newer systems, or programmer error.  Systems calls occur often enough that nanosecond or even picosecond improvements can help.

Other instances it may prove worthy is for opcode LUTs inside emulators such as MAME.

Comment: I completely disagree. For the general case I would prefer method A because of the increased readability.

Comment: So it is not microscopically faster, it is picoscopically faster?

Comment: @Martin I found a paper with similar opinion, but similar to Jens the compiler has more opportunity to optimise *method B* than *A*.

Comment: @Steve-o: That's because you are using C-like function pointers. Convert it to use C++ functors and the compiler should be able to trivially optimize it.